# VSCode - Cursor moves left on AltGr. How to fix it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I type the following text in my vscode editor:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/[Link to Stackoverflow]
omg[
```

I get this result:

```
https://stackoverflow.com[/Link to Stackoverflo]w
om[g
```

I've observed that the back shifting of the cursor happens as soon as I press the [`AltGr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key) on my [german+layout+keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout).

Comment: Have you checked that it's not an auto-formatting extension or some sort?

Comment: I have disabled all extensions, still...

Comment: Note that you'd normally do `[text](https://some.url)` in Markdown, not the other way around

Comment: @HongOoi I use [asciidoc](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/syntax-quick-reference/#links).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I switched the keyboard.dispatch setting to

```
"keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode"
```

That fixed it.