# QWebEngineView interprets AltGr press as left arrow in WSL2

Tags: qt, keyboard, windows-subsystem-for-linux, x11, qwebengineview

**Context:**

Custom Qt application embedding a QWebEngineView widget used to display an Auth0 page.
Compiled for Fedora against Qt5.15.2, run on Windows in a WSL2 distribution. vcxsrv is used to display the X11 window.

**Symptoms:**

In the email text field, when I try to type `@` using the `AltGr`+`à` key combination (french keyboard), the cursor jumps 1 character left as soon as I press the `AltGr` key. Oddly, the `@` character is properly added. For instance, if I try to type `test@`, the result is `tes@t` and the cursor is right after the `@`.
Each time I press AltGr alone, the cursor jumps left.
In a QLineEdit, no issue typing `@`

**Tests done:**

- chromium-browser launched in the same WSL2 distribution: works as expected (QtWebEngineView is based on chromium)
- Played with the `locale` settings but no success
- Played with the `QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS` env var but no success ([list of Chromium flags](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/))

**Quite similar issue:**
[VSCode - Cursor moves left on AltGr. How to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67804948/vscode-cursor-moves-left-on-altgr-how-to-fix-it)

Any help to understand what is the culprit would be greatly appreciated!